# How To Create A Sticky Navbar with Drop Down Menu using HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, navbar

I am creating a HTML web page which contains a sticky navbar with drop down menu. However, when I created one, the dropdown menu does not works in the sticky navbar and so goes vise versa. below is the screenshot of both the result of the two codes.

[*image with dropdown menu but without sticky navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3gQL.png)

[*image with sticky navbar but without dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6AzF.png)

below is the code for "image with dropdown menu but without sticky navbar"

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

   .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }

  .topnav a {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: sticky;
  }



  .active {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
  }

  .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
  }

  .dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="header">
        <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
    <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon"     onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
    <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
  </div>

  <h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
  <p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer do not support sticky positioning and Safari         requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>


  <script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
      x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
      x.className = "topnav";
    }
  }
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

below is the code for "image with sticky navbar but without dropdown menu"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-    awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>


body {
  font-size: 20px;
}
body {margin:0;}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
    
/*======================================================================*/

body {
  background-color:white;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #38444d;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
    
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: DarkSalmon;
  color: white;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Down</h2>
  <p>Scroll down to see the sticky effect.</p>
</div>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="javascript:void(1)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<h3>Sticky Navigation Bar Example</h3>
<p>The navbar will <strong>stick</strong> to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer do not support sticky positioning and Safari requires a -webkit- prefix.</p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>
<p>Some text to enable scrolling. </p>


<footer>
  <p>Author: Hege Refsnes<br>
  <a href="mailto:hege@example.com">hege@example.com</a></p>
</footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Please i need some help with this as i am new to html and css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, Remove overflow property from the navbar, and add a min-height to it like this,

```
.topnav {
      /* overflow: hidden; */
      background-color: #333;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      min-height: 45px;
    }
```

Since you are using the float property in navigation items, it may cause trouble

The working code [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/abd1mrwp/)

Comment: hi there, thanks a lot for the help. the navbar works well now. may i know how does the float property cause this navbar to not work?

Comment: and, for the second code, the sticky navbar is working but just the dropdown menu is not. do you have any solution for it?

Comment: @thanabalantharmalingam, Same remove the overflow: hidden property and add a min-height property to the ul selector. The Second Code [link](https://jsfiddle.net/36vc7bxy/)

Comment: the second code it works too due to you help. but how does the min-height property work in this particular part?

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code because the overflow hidden dropdown menu was not visible checkout this code. If you want then I can paste the full code here. I hope this will help you.

Your first code solution

```
 .topnav {
            background-color: #333;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:768px){
            .topnav {
            display: flex;
        }  
        }
@media screen and (max-width: 767.98px){
    .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
        }  
}
```

Your second code solution

```
ul {
    display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: #38444d;
}
```

Comment: hi there, thank a lot for the help.
for the first  code you had given, the navbar when slightly different than the default, whee the style of the name (eg. About, Home) has change to link shortcut.

for the second code you shared, there is no changes in my code. i am so sorry for no changes in my code. does it works on yours?

Comment: Yes this is working in my side, Did you add display: flex; and need to remove overflow: hidden;

Comment: Oh my!!! I am terribly sorry for that. i might notice that line only. it seems your codes works too in the code. Thanks a lot for your help appreciate it a lot.

Comment: may i know why do you have to remove the "overflow: hidden;" property? it seem that mr.madhan did the same as well.